# Does scons support to build a target without building its dependency?

Tags: scons

In SConstruct or SConscript, we can specify the dependency information, I just wish to know if scons has an extra option that doesn't build dependent modules? (Ignore dependency information for a target)

E.g.(from bdbaddog) a depends on b, b depends on c.

Case 1: I want to build a without scons rebuilding b or c if they need it. How to do this?

Case 2: I want to build b and not rebuild a. In this case, how to specify building b on the command line, or just have a never update if b updates?

Comment: Please provide a more concrete example (in code) of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean:  a depends on b, b depends on c.  You want to build a without scons rebuilding b or c if they need it?  Or you want to build b and not rebuild a? In the latter case, would you want to specify building b on the command line, or just have a never update if b updates?